# Как сделать последовательное выполнение задач?

Tags: python, числовые-последовательности

```
if not was_min_money and len(previous_bets) > katar_sandar * 2 + 1:
    for test in range(katar_sandar):
        if previous_bets[-(test * 2 + 2)] == previous_bets[-(test * 2 + 3)] and not was_min_money:
            check_katar_sandar += 1
if check_katar_sandar > 0 and katar_sandar != 0:
    is_katar_sandar = True
if is_katar_sandar and not was_min_money and previous_won_bones[-1] in previous_bets[-1]): ***(Чтобы здесь previous_won_bones[-1] in previous_bets[-1] выполнялся после is_katar_sandar а не вместе с ним )
    was_min_money = True
    list_count = 0
    bet_size = scale_list[list_count]['start_bet_size']
    lose_count = 0
    previous_timer = 4
    virtual_money = old_virtual_money
    max_virtual_money = old_virtual_money
    previous_bets = []
    is_make_bet = False
    continue
```

Comment: А previous_won_bones[-1] in previous_bets[-1] - это вообще-то говоря не выполнение. Это логическая проверка  условия и только. Так что уточните свой вопрос.

Comment: Да Точно! (Я недавно начал изучать python). Вопрос такой чтобы он проверял их по последовательности (Например: сначала он проверил is_katar_sandar, если выполнен то после проверил previous_won_bones[-1] in previous_bets[-1])

Answer (score 1):

То что вы только что начали изучать Python это конечно похвально, только вот не понимаю, как вы это делаете? Рекомендую все таки хотя-бы краешком глаза прочитать, что такое условный оператор и как их надо оформлять в Python.

```
   if is_katar_sandar and not was_min_money : 
       # тут делаете то, что НЕ связано с третьим условием
       if previous_won_bones[-1] in previous_bets[-1]: 
           # тут делаете то, что связано с всеми тремя условиями
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное